# Error while connecting to SQL server through Django

Tags: django, python-2.7

In settings file, I have given SQL SERVER Database connection values like this.

```
DATABASES = {

'default': {

        'NAME': 'AdventureWorks2014',

        'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',

        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',

        'USER': '',

        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}
```

**Versions:**
Django `v:1.11`
Python `v:2.7`
django-mssql `v:1.8`
pip `v:9.0`

**Development Platform:**
Visual Studio

After the database connection values changes, I have used the command

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Here I got the error:

> Executing manage.py makemigrations
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\manage.py", line 17, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py", line 338, in execute
>       django.setup()
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django__init__.py", line 27, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
>       app_config.import_models()
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
>     File "C:\Python27\Lib\importlib__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in 
>       from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 52, in 
>       class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 124, in **new**
>       new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 325, in add_to_class
>       value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class
>       self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db__init__.py", line 33, in **getattr**
>       return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in **getitem**
>       conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\sqlserver_ado\base.py", line 184, in **init**
>       super(DatabaseWrapper, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "E:\Django Projects\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\DjangoMSSQLDatabaseConn\VirtualEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 96, in **init**
>       self.client = self.client_class(self)
>   TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       'NoneType' object is not callable
>   The interactive Python process has exited.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Hi, you had a solution for this error?

Comment: No @PHPedro, do you have the solution. I am looking for the solution.Help on this?